# MvvmCross sometimes has problems with IoC

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, ioc-container

I encounter quite bad problem with MvvmCross IoC resolving.

We have a big application that registers about 100 different services and 6 plugins.
Sometimes we are getting problems with resolving these services. Most time it works fine, but then at Xamarin.Insights I can see that at production, there are some problems that happens(NOT ALWAYS), for example this:

```
Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveExceptionFailed to resolve 
type Cirrious.MvvmCross.Localization.IMvxTextProvider
Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Resolve(Type)
at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Resolve<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Localization.IMvxTextProvider> () <0x00023>
at Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.Resolve<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Localization.IMvxTextProvider> () <0x0004b>
<project>.Droid.Code.Menu.MenuActivity<TextMessageDetailsViewModel>.OnCreate(Bundle)
Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_(intptr, intptr, intptr)
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.715a16ed-a35e-4884-89f1-5e2568dbe846 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00043>
```

What can cause the problem that only sometimes it doesn't work?

Comment: I typically see this error when there is an exception thrown while trying to create the service or view model the first time.  Any way to see if you can find the inner exception?

Comment: There is no inner exception :/